# Generics Node declaration

Tags: c#, generics, nested-generics

Microsoft gives this as an Bubble sort example for learning generics.  It makes sense until I get to lines 76 and 77.  How are those declarations possible?  Node is a class.  Don't you have to instantiate it with new?
How would you optimize the sort?  Which is part is generic and which is non-generic?

```
1   public class GenericList<T> : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>
2       {
3           protected Node head;
4           protected Node current = null;
5   
6           // Nested class is also generic on T
7           protected class Node
8           {
9               public Node next;
10              private T data;  //T as private member datatype
11   
12              public Node(T t)  //T used in non-generic constructor
13              {
14                  next = null;
15                  data = t;
16              }
17  
18              public Node Next
19              {
20                  get { return next; }
21                  set { next = value; }
22              }
23  
24              public T Data  //T as return type of property
25              {
26                  get { return data; }
27                  set { data = value; }
28              }
29          }
30  
31          public GenericList()  //constructor
32          {
33              head = null;
34          }
35  
36          public void AddHead(T t)  //T as method parameter type
37          {
38              Node n = new Node(t);
39              n.Next = head;
40              head = n;
41          }
42  
43          // Implementation of the iterator
44          public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
45          {
46              Node current = head;
47              while (current != null)
48              {
49                  yield return current.Data;
50                  current = current.Next;
51                  
52              }
53          }
54  
55          System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
56          {
57              return GetEnumerator();
58          }
59      }
60  
61      public class SortedList<T> : GenericList<T> where T : System.IComparable<T>
62      {
63          // A simple, unoptimized sort algorithm that 
64          // orders list elements from lowest to highest:
65  
66          public void BubbleSort()
67          {
68              if (null == head || null == head.Next)
69              {
70                  return;
71              }
72              bool swapped;
73  
74              do
75              {
76                  Node previous = null;
77                  Node current = head;
78  
79                  
80                  //Console.WriteLine(previous.GetType());
81                  //Console.ReadLine();
82  
83                  swapped = false;
84                  
85                   
86                  //Debug.WriteLine(p);
87                  //Debug.WriteLine("Testing " + current.ToString());
88  
89                  while (current.next != null)
90                  {
91                      //  Because we need to call this method, the SortedList
92                      //  class is constrained on IEnumerable<T>
93                      if (current.Data.CompareTo(current.next.Data) > 0)
94                      {
95                          Node tmp = current.next;
96                          current.next = current.next.next;
97                          tmp.next = current;
98  
99                          if (previous == null)
100                         {
101                             head = tmp;
102                         }
103                         else
104                         {
105                             previous.next = tmp;
106                         }
107                         previous = tmp;
108                         swapped = true;
109                     }
110                     else
111                     {
112                         previous = current;
113                         current = current.next;
114                     }
115                 }
116             } while (swapped);
117         }
118     }
```

Answer (score 2):

A `class` type in C# can be initialized with `null` or a value which is of a compatible type with the declaration.  Lines 76 and 77 look like so

```
Node previous = null;
Node current = head;
```

Here the value `null` is legal.  It essentially says "I have no value".  The assignment to `head` is also legal because `head` is also of type `Node`.  The result is the two references `head` and `current` refer to the same `Node` object value.  Modifying the `Node` instance through one of the references will be visible to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `previous` and `next` to `null` and `head` respectively. It's an assignment operation, just like any other. You don't need to use new unless you're actually creating a new instance of the object.

The generic parts are anything that refers to `T`. It's a generic type that is supplied when the class is instanciated. A good example is `List<T>`, which creates a list of objects of type `T`. You could instance this as `List<string>` for a list of strings, `List<int>` for a list of ints, etc.

Answer (score 0):

These are **references** that could be pointing to **instances** of a **class** or can be just `null`.

You can assign references to other references:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo();
Foo f2 = f1;
Foo f3 = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

No objects are being instantiated on lines 76 and 77 in that code. As you said, `Node` is a class. Classes in .NET are always reference types which means that:

1. The value of a variable of a reference type is a *reference* to an object (or nothing).
2. Variables of a reference type can be assigned the value `null`, which means that the variable references nothing.
3. Assigning one variable of a reference type to another variable of a reference type copies the reference, not the object.